# After updating from Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04 I lost my desktop

Tags: boot

Message said:
'You have packages from the HWE installed that are going out of support on 2016-08-04. 
there is a graphics stack installed on this system. An upgrade to a configuration supported for the full lifetime of the LTS will become available on 2016-07-21 and can be installed by running 'update-manager' in the dash.'

I've looked at several questions on the forum and tried to run the update-manager to install the supported HWE, but have been unsuccessful in doing so. I've used Ubuntu linux for a while, but am a total newbie on the underlying structure of linux. How can I get back to my desktop?  Thanks.

Comment: The question is a little unclear. First, have you got access to a root shell?

Comment: What do you mean "I lost my desktop"? What appears on screen?

Comment: I have no GUI after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.  Only a Linux window with which I can enter Linux commands.  Whether that is root, I don't know.  As I said, I'm not very literate on Linux.

Comment: Rather than upgrade I found simpler to make one system partition (e.g. 20GB) plus one data partition (all remaining space less 20GB) plus a second system partition (plus possibly swap). Then at upgrade time just install a fresh system on the unused system partition. This make sure that if new system has some malfunction, I always have a bootable system. Perhaps you should write Ubuntu installer on a USB stick, boot, ask it to shrink existing partition to make room for a system partition, then install a fresh system. That one would just work. Have your permanent data on your data partition.

Comment: Useful for future, but doesn't help my current situation.  Thanks.

Comment: it depends. If no precious data exists on the machine, the easiest way for beginner is just wipe it and install clean. If precious data exists, shrinking partition to install a second system will provide you a working one without hassle, and a way to access your precious data. If useful data is low volume, just boot on a live USB to access it, copy it elsewhere and wipe/reinstall the machine. All those are easiest options for beginners. (Be careful in all cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure, but if you could install GNOME environment on your desktop, you can get back your desktop. I presume you have unity environment installed previously.

Comment: Translating for the OP: this may translate to trying to get a root shell and then typing `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. This may or may not solve your actual problem.

Comment: When I did this, I got the response that Ubuntu desktop is already installed - newest version 1.417.  I think the problem may be updating the HWE, but I've already tried that several times after viewing other qs on that topic to no avail.